# gradle google drive dependency not getting resolved

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I am trying to run the code

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;

import java.io.IOException;

// ...

public class MyClass {

  // ...

  /**
   * Print a file's parents.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @param fileId ID of the file to print parents for.
   */
  private static void printParents(Drive service, String fileId) {
    try {
      ParentList parents = service.parents().list(fileId).execute();

      for (ParentReference parent : parents.getItems()) {
        System.out.println("File Id: " + parent.getId());
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
  }

  // ...

}
```

which is used to know the parents detail.

Dependencies added are

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev59-1.22.0'
}
```

Code sample has been taken from [from this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/list)

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ParentReference;
```

Above import is actually not getting resolved. Please help me.

Comment: invalidate and restart then perform a clean.

Comment: @Nitish Kumar ,  You got it working?. if yes, How ?